# Animating cell more than once

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift3

I have a uitableview cell and it will animate when the cell is displayed. These cells are in tableviews and these tableviews are tabs of a uitabbarcontroller. But if a user presses one of the four tabs for the first time then the cells will animate, but if a user clicks a new tab and goes back to the previous tab the cells will not animate. How can I make it so that the cells animate everytime the tableview is presented. Here is my code, can someone please show me how i can make the cell animate each time the view is presented and not only when the cell is presented.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let rotationTransform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DIdentity, 10, 10, 0)
        cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.6, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.2, initialSpringVelocity: 0.1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reload the data on view will appear controller method:**

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    tableview.reloadData()
}
```

Also, you may need to reset to the starting state before you animate again. why? because when you scroll your table view the cells that appears will not animate. they will have the final state after animation (reusable cells).

Another thing that you may scoll and the top cell will disappear before completing the animation. I am not sure what would happen. maybe it will not take its final state. and when you get back to it or that cell get reused that cell will not have the final state. but, if you reset to the first state before you start animating again that will solve all the problems.

**reset animation:**

```
cell.layer.transform = nil
// you may need to layout the cell. not sure. after this.
// then the rest of your code that animates the cell.
```

Comment: where do I put this cell.layer.transform = nil

Comment: on willDisplay before you animate. it resets to the starting state  before animation to prevent un-wanted behavior

Comment: and to allow the bottom cells that didnt not appear yet to animate.

Comment: so it will be the first line in willDisplay right before this let rotationTransform = CATr

Comment: I am not sure though if cell.layer.transform = nil is enough to reset the animation.

Comment: will I am not sure. I guess that this line of yours cell.layer.transform = rotationTransform do the thing. = nil not needed. but, it was worth mentionning. goodluck